# Global variable in angular2 whose value can be changed

Tags: javascript, angular, observable

I have injected one service while bootstrapping to use global variables:

```
 bootstrap(AppComponent, [ GloablService ]);
```

**global.service.ts**

```
import {Http} from 'angular2/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {Observer} from 'rxjs/Observer';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/share';

export class GlobalService {
  baseUrl:string;
  constructor() {
    this.baseUrl='http://localhost:8080'; 
  }
  setBaseUrl(url:string) {
    this.baseUrl=url;  
  }
  getBaseUrl() {
    return this.baseUrl;  
  }
}
```

Now I have bootstrapped this service along with my root component and i am able to access the variable successfully.

But whenever I change the value of the variable in nested components the change is not reflected globally.

I tried to use observables too but no use.

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't add `providers: [ GloablService ]` on any component, otherwise the components will get a different instance. Only provide it once at `bootstrap()` like you did, or only at the root component `AppComponent`.

Comment: I have not added as providers in any nested components.. i am facing trouble with observables only. seems like the code might be deprecated. :(

Comment: Shouldn't you have to add `@Injectable()` above the class?

Comment: Your question doesn't show how you use observables. It might be caused by observables that emit values before other components have subscribed.

Comment: @echonax `@Injectable()` should be added to all classes that are injected per the style guide, but it's only required if the constructor has parameters.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer the value of global variable is not changed when I try to change it..why is that?

Comment: Hard to tell from the information in your question. Can you create a Plunker?